# DMRaid Not Detecting its disks

Tags: partitioning, raid, disk, dmraid

We had a software raid using dmraid in an ubuntu 14.04 box. For some reason, we changed the sata ports per disk. The disks were removed and added again to the case but on different sata ports probably. Now when we boot the computer the DmRaid fails to load and reports that it has no members.

The disks are detected normaly. Each one of them is detected as a raid member.
How can we add again the disks to the RAID array without losing our data?